# Custom HTML Code creates empty list in IE 9

Tags: java, html, internet-explorer

I have a custom HTML stored in database. The html is simple ordered list

```
    Before the dawn <ul> <B><li>Blah blah blah !!</ul><ul>
    <li>Do not combine capital letters Blah blah</b></ul>
    <P> For any questions, please refer to your customer support
```

The code is working perfectly in Midori, Opera, Firefox, Seamonkey, Chrome and IE 8 however it displays an additional bullet list item after the last UL with an empty text this happens only in IE 9. Is this happening because am not closing the paragraph tag?

Note: The custom HTML goes within a Form

Comment: You should always close your tags if they're not self terminating (e.g. <br/>) at least for reasons of best practice. Otherwise you can pretty much consider the outcome in-deterministic across browsers. Upload your entire page markup here and fix pick away at the errors: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: @butallmj the <li> element is self terminating. I agree that it's better practice to close though.

Comment: @imjared, good to know about li's being self terminating. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, because you're not closing your List Items with `</li>`

```
Before the dawn <ul><li><b>Blah blah blah !!</b></li>
<li><b>Do not combine capital letters Blah blah</b></li></ul>
```

You should also use just one Unordered List `<ul></ul>` instead of having one for every list item. And, although it may work otherwise, display tags like bold `<b>` should ideally go inside the structure tags like list item `<li>`.